# Is it possible to prove this inequality?

Tags: fractions

Suppose I have the following pairs of variables:

- $a$ , $\hat{a}$
- $b$ , $\hat{b}$
- $c$ , $\hat{c}$
- $d$ , $\hat{d}$

Now, suppose I have the following functions:

- Function 1:

$$ F(A, B, C, D) =  \frac{\frac{A}{B}}{\frac{C}{D}}$$

- Function 2:

$$ G(A, B, C, D) =  \frac{\frac{A}{A+B}}{\frac{C}{C+D}}$$

**My Question:** When $a >> \hat{a}$ and  $c >> \hat{c}$, us it possible to mathematically prove that  : $$|F(a, b, c, d) - F(\hat{a}, \hat{b}, \hat{c}, \hat{d})|  <  |G(a, b, c, d) - G(\hat{a}, \hat{b}, \hat{c}, \hat{d})|$$

That is: if we fix some values of $b$ and $d$ - and then, when $(a,\hat{a})$ differ by a lot and $(c,\hat{c})$ differ by a lot, is the above inequality correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a = 10^6$, $b = c = d = 1$, $\hat{a} = 0$, $\hat{b} = 1 = \hat{d}$, $\hat{c} = -10^6$, we have $a >> \hat{a}$, and $c >> \hat{c}$, but

\begin{align}
|F(10^6,1,1,1) - F(0,1,-10^6,1)| = 10^6
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
|G(10^6,1,1,1) - G(0,1,-10^6,1)| = \frac{2(10^6)}{10^6 + 1} \approx 2
\end{align}

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! suppose if all variables can only be positive integers: is the inequality still true?