# Proving a Constrained Ineqality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, constraints

Suppose I have the following pairs of variables:

- $a$ , $\hat{a}$
- $b$ , $\hat{b}$
- $c$ , $\hat{c}$
- $d$ , $\hat{d}$

**With the following constraints such that** $a, \hat{a}, b, \hat{b}, c, \hat{c}, d, \hat{d} \in \mathbb{N}$

Now, suppose I have the following functions:

- Function 1:

$$ F(A, B, C, D) =  \frac{\frac{A}{B}}{\frac{C}{D}}$$

- Function 2:

$$ G(A, B, C, D) =  \frac{\frac{A}{A+B}}{\frac{C}{C+D}}$$

**My Question:** When $a >> \hat{a}$ and  $c >> \hat{c}$, us it possible to mathematically prove that  : $$|F(a, b, c, d) - F(\hat{a}, \hat{b}, \hat{c}, \hat{d})|  <  |G(a, b, c, d) - G(\hat{a}, \hat{b}, \hat{c}, \hat{d})|$$

That is: if we fix some values of $b$ and $d$ - and then, when $(a,\hat{a})$ differ by a lot and $(c,\hat{c})$ differ by a lot, is the above inequality correct?

Thanks!

**Note:** A related question I asked **without constraints** [Is it possible to prove this inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771585/is-it-possible-to-prove-this-inequality)